# Wordpress Page - I need to GET variables

Tags: wordpress

I am not a wordpress guy and a client needs me to modify some pages. Someone else has created the entire site in wordpress.

I am having trouble with a query string that contains variables.

wordpresssite.com/pages-using-template/?variable=something

This causes the page to get thrown to the default 404 for the site..

Any suggestions on which file i need to fix this in and how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> wordpresssite.com/pages-using-template/?variable=something

That's giving you a 404 error, probably because you're trying to add the query string variable to the home page of the site.  There's no "file" that fixes this - WordPress is dynamic.  the .htaccess rules handle the URL rewrites ("pretty permalinks")

So I guess you need to give more information on what it is you're trying to do.  There's not going to really be a way to "fix" the URL without breaking the rest of the site (it's possible, but I'm betting that whatever it is you're trying to do requires a much simpler solution).

What query string are you trying to add in? For what reason?

For example, I recently did a WordPress site from someone who needed a directory on one page of the site, that had a custom search from in it.  I created a function that would $_GET the URL of the page and add the search query to it, and then return the end user to the page with the results there.

You also have to be careful about the $_GET in your functions - you want to be sure they're protected against injection attacks by using $wpdb->escape($_GET['xxx']).